# Yii2 display the lastname and firstname into select2 widget

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

I used select2 widget for Yii2. I tried to display the lastname and firstname in the dropdown, but it didn't work.

However, it worked when I only put lastname or firstname. How can I display the two using select2 widget in Yii2?

Here is the code which only runs for one attribute:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','first_name'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select User'],
    'pluginOptions' => [ 'allowClear' => true ]
]); ?>
```

---

I want to display in dropdown a complete name, for example:

> Ping lacson
>
> Erap Strada

Answer (score 3):

[ArrayHelper::map()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#map()-detail) method can get a callable for 2nd & 3rd arguments. Just use it like this:

```
'data' => ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(), 'id', function (User $model) {
    return "{$model->first_name} {$model->last_name}";
}),
```